# What's the significance of the App Verifier error pattern `fafa`?

Tags: c++, windows, application-verifier

My program is crashing in app verifier and I don't fully understand the crash.  I have a buffer which is dynamically allocated thus from the number of bytes in a file:

```
DWORD dwSizeBytes = (DWORD)liSize.QuadPart+2;
TCHAR* JSONBufferW = new TCHAR [dwSizeBytes/sizeof(TCHAR)];
memset(JSONBufferW, 0, dwSizeBytes);
```

Where `dwSizeBytes` (I can see this in the crash dump) is `38`.  After this I read some data from a file:

```
if(!ReadFile(hFile, JSONBufferW, dwSizeBytes, &dwSizeBytes, NULL))
{
    status = GetLastError();
    TRACE_ERROR(g_hTrace, "ReadFile() failed for %S, error code=%d", strCompletePath, status);
}
```

This assigns `36` to `dwSizeBytes` leaving the last two bytes in the buffer NULL so that the buffer is NULL terminated.  However under app verifier this later causes a crash when I attempt to construct a `std::wstring` from the buffer.

When I look at the buffer's allocation block in windbg I see that it looks like this:

```
0:022> dd 0x00000000`07560fd0-0x48 0x00000000`07560fd0
00000000`07560f88  00001000 00000000 abcdbbbb 00000000
00000000`07560f98  07191000 00000000 00000026 00000000
00000000`07560fa8  00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000`07560fb8  00000000 00000000 0025a230 00000000
00000000`07560fc8  00001000 dcbabbbb 0022007b
```

Note the `0x26` which shows my buffer is supposed to be 38 in size.  Now I look at the buffer it's self and see:

```
0:022> dc 0x00000000`07560fd0
00000000`07560fd0  0022007b 006f006d 00650064 003a0022  {.".m.o.d.e.".:.
00000000`07560fe0  006d0022 006e0061 00610075 0022006c  ".m.a.n.u.a.l.".
00000000`07560ff0  000a007d d0d0fafa d0d0d0d0 d0d0d0d0  }...............
```

This shows that my buffer has been filled by `ReadFile` but where the `NULL` should have been left at `buf[36]` and `buf[37]` (remember the memset) there is an app verifier fill code `fafa` (remember the unicode bytes are flipped so `d0d0` is actually after `fafa`.

I've looked [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jiangyue/archive/2010/03/16/windows-heap-overrun-monitoring.aspx): which has shown me how app verifier leaves these fill codes after allocations.  But `fafa` is not listed, so what does it mean?  And why is it in the place where `memset` should have cleared?

Comment: I have to admit I don't quite follow your debugging, but one thing that catches my eye is `new TCHAR [dwSizeBytes/sizeof(TCHAR)];`. This integer division will *round down*, so you overrun your `JSONBufferW` when trying to read `dwSizeBytes` into it. In fact, even the `memset` will write over the boundaries of the allocated memory region.

Comment: That's a good point, although in this case `dwSizeBytes` is an even number and sizeof(TCHAR) is 2 so it should be ok.  The file is full of UTF16 so it shouldn't ever be an issue in fact.

Comment: What are you doing between `ReadFile` and the `wstring ctor`? Did you check the buffer content directly after `ReadFile`? Common sense suggests that `ReadFile` only wrote 36 bytes into the buffer, but I cannot find a statement in the documentation that prohibits ReadFile from modifying the rest of the buffer (the last two bytes). So what result do you get when you set dwSizeBytes to 36 before calling `ReadFile`?

Comment: `ReadFile` would have to be fairly evil to tell me that it's read 36 bytes but to have modified all 38 of the bytes in my buffer....  I did think about forcing the last two bytes to be NULL after `ReadFile` perhaps that's the answer.  I can't reproduce this crash myself so I want to be sure I've fixed it before returning it to the customer :-(

Comment: @WernerHenze - Nothing which touches the buffer (or any memory), the wstring ctor is the very next thing to read/write to the buffer.

Comment: Well, the code is notably broken.  You are asking ReadFile() to read 38 bytes.  You should not be surprised when you actually get 38 bytes.  You must pass dwSizeBytes-sizeof(TCHAR) to ensure your null terminator survives.

Extrapolating, you'll only get less than the requested number of bytes when you are reading from the end of the file.  The kind of scenario where you are reading data from a log file that's being written to by another process.  That kind of code can randomly fail when the process that's writing the file is flushing its write buffer at an inopportune time.

Just fix the bug.

Comment: @HansPassant - I take your point and will implement this I expect.  I still think it's odd that ReadFile will tell you it's read 36 bytes but actually write 38 to your buffer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a source for this at the moment, but one of the features AppVerifier does is completely fills your buffer with a pattern prior to invoking ReadFile.  You request to read 38 bytes, AppVerifier fills your buffer with 38 bytes of pattern, and ReadFile only reads 36 bytes from the file.  Thus your last 2 bytes are fill pattern rather than the expected NULL characters.

Comment: Hmm, that certainly sounds plausible and might explain the odd `fafa` pattern I'm seeing.  Cheers.